# How do I get old UserID as of Graph API v2.0?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, upgrade

In numerous applications I've written, every time I want to give user an opportunity to log in through Facebook, I get their user id after logging in and pair it with my app's user account. However, after an introducion of v2.0, I'm not pretty sure how should I pair them. If I upgrade now without making any changes but changing API endpoints, I end up with duplicate accounts due to inconsistency between User IDs (I'll be searching for a new (APP scoped) used id in database with old IDs). How should I upgrade without losing every user consistency?
To demonstrate how do I retreive their accounts, I'll join a bit of PHP here

```
<?php
$user = $db->fetchQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE fb_id = ".$facebookSDK->getUser());
```

Answer (score 4):

Consistency should be fine here, within a single app.

If a user has already authenticated with an app prior to 4/30/2014, the id you receive will not change.  For new users authenticating on or after 4/30/2014, you'll get an 'app-scoped' id which has the same format but is not the canonical 'fbid'.

For apps owned by the same developer, the Business Manager can provide mappings for users across app-scoped ids in different apps.

https://business.facebook.com/

Comment: That's the problem I'm solving - I've got thousands of people who registered during v1.0 and now, due to their inconsistent "new" fbid, they'll obtain a new account instead of the old one if I start getting app-scoped id.

Comment: That's not the way it's supposed to work.  If they already authorized your app, you should continue to get the actual fbid.  You may want to open a bug on developers.facebook.com in order to address this.

Comment: If a user authorised your app already, you'll get the same user ID for them that you always did, it won't change

Answer (score -3):

There is a dirty hack to retrieve original facebook id

http://graph.facebook.com/**app-scoped-id** this returns facebook public informaton along with **username**

Then you make another graph api call with **username**
http://graph.facebook.com/**username**

This will returns the original facebook id and other public information, instead of app-scoped-id

Comment: v2.0 no longer returns usernames